# Spring resttemplate POST body

Tags: spring, post, resttemplate

I am trying to do a POST an object using Spring 3 resttemplate. Object is being marshalling correctly..but it is being posted as 'XForms:Model' rather than the request body.

```
HttpEntity<InputsRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<InputsRequest>(request);

ResponseEntity<MyResponse> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(baseURL,  entity, MyResponse.class);
```

Have tried using `postForLocation` and `postForObject`

Many thanks for looking.